# How do I make a JSON file update itself when I add properties

Tags: javascript, json, object

So I made a program that would create a property and put in an object inside a JSON file. And well it works, the only problem is that it gets rid of the changes as soon as the program is restarted. Does anyone know how to make the JSON file automaticly update itself? I am pretty new to programming so any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: JSON files can't update themselves. The program that updates the data needs to write it back out to the file.

Comment: Well how do I do that? As I said I am pretty new at programming

Comment: Read the file, call `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object. Update the object, call `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to a JSON string. Write that to the file.

Comment: You said you wrote a program that puts the object into a JSON file. You update the file the same way you created it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using nodejs and have a file named `jsonFile.json` in the same directory as your script. Here is what you can do to save the changes back to the json file.

```
// These 2 lines import the json file to get what is already there in the json file

const jsonFile = require('./jsonFile')
console.log(jsonFile)

// DO YOUR PROCESSING HERE


// Then write to the json file to save your changes
const fs = require('fs')
const objectToWrite = {
    property1: 6
}
fs.writeFileSync('jsonFile.json', JSON.stringify(objectToWrite))
```